# How can we retrieve the transaction address of any transaction?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, addresses, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Once a transaction is completed on Ethereum Wallet then we can see the address of the transaction in our geth console : 
[ **Tx("{txn address}") to: "{contract_address}"** ]before mining starts. Pic attached for reference.

[image]

How can I capture that address and the address of contract which is shown just along transaction address in any format possible so that I can show the transaction address in UI ?

Answer (score 3):

First copy and assign the transaction hash to a variable like so:

`var tx = "0x123456789abcdef"`

Then get the transaction recept(assigned to variable info).

`var info = web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx);`

Press `info` to display the full info of the transaction, including the transaction addresses.

Comment: Where should I " press info " how can I see the contents of info in console or in UI ?

Comment: In the console. But you can also use a block explorer like etherchain.org.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the transactions in each block using `web3.eth.getblock(blocknumber)`. To know about the contract address using the transaction hash, you can use `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(Transaction_Hash)`. You can display all these details on UI using web3 API and JSON-RPC.